# Show full content if div is fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here i have two long `div`s. The first `div` is fixed, and I want to show all elements of `div.content` when user scrolls (because I have full elements on first `div`.
How can i do this?

```
<div style="display: block; width: 100%;">

    <div style="float: left; position: relative; z-index: 0;">
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <div class="content" style="padding-top: 10px; top: 10px; position: fixed;">

                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                 Show element after user scrolls
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 11%; width: 67%;">

        Right DIV FUll LONG TEXT

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't clear what you want. You have the fixed menu group and long content div like that: https://jsfiddle.net/zaaafd3k/. When you're scrolling, the menu group is fixed and the long content div is scrolling. What kind of behaviour you do want?

Comment: @hsrv i have full elements (menu) and my div not show all elements when i scroll, i just want to show all when i scrolls

Comment: No clear problem statement or example!

Comment: add `height: 100%;` to your `content` div.

Answer (score 1):

Just check this out. I think just in you fixed content block you have to add some height then give overflow scroll.

```html
<div style="display: block; width: 100%;">

    <div style="float: left; position: relative; z-index: 0;">
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <div class="content" style="padding-top: 10px; top: 10px; position: fixed;overflow-y: scroll;height: 186px;">

                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">MENU</div>
                Show element after user scrolls

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 11%; width: 67%;">

        Right DIV FUll LONG TEXT

    </div>
```

Comment: can i make with no overflow this function ?

Comment: A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or the browser window itself. The viewport doesn't change when the window is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is when the page is scrolled. That's why content will cut. So we have give fixed height and scroll bar.